# Compiler Error CS0117

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I have two Projects in one Solution and I want to call a Method from Project1 in Project 2. I already refered the Namespace of Project1 in Project2. The Method from Project1 looks like this:

```
public void pauseCapturing(bool checkPause)
    {
        if (checkPause)
        {
            backgroundThread.Suspend();
        }
        else
        {
            backgroundThread.Resume();
        }
    }
```

In Project2 I call that Method like that:

```
private void buttonPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonPause.Enabled = false;

        NamespaceProject1.Class.pauseCapturing(true);
    }
```

When I try to run the code i get the following error:

> Error 1   'NamespaceProject1.Class' does not contain a definition for
>   'pauseCapturing'

I didn't really found a helpful answer to solve my problem.

Comment: @SonerGönül: why he can not have `Class`?

Comment: @SonerGönül: yes `class` is a KeyWord but not `Class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to create an `instance` for accessing the `methods` declared in another class.

in your case you have created method `pauseCapturing()` as an `non-static` method hence need an `instance` to call it.

Note : if the method is declared as a `static` then you can use `class name` to access it.

Try This:

```
NamespaceProject1.Class obj=new NamespaceProject1.Class();
obj.pauseCapturing(true);
```

Comment: After changing it I got another error: Error 1 'NamespaceProject1.Class' does not contain a definition for 'pauseCapturing' and no extension method 'pauseCapturing' accepting a first argument of type 'NamespaceProject1.Class' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @user3065722: well , could you please show me your Class design?

Comment: I found out that there was something wrong in my settings. I resetted them and then it worked. :)